# How to update json file in AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs

I want to update the existing json file in AngularJS

JSON file:

```
 {  
    "text1": "Click here to edit!",
    "text2": "Click here to edit!",
    "text3": "Click here to edit!",
    "text4": "Click here to edit!"  
}
```

I want to update this JSON file as:

```
text1: "Abc"
```

and save this changes in JSON file

Comment: Is the JSON file in the server?

Comment: @Gaurav Quick question
Are you trying to send updated/modified json to server?

Comment: @Gaurav Can you clearly mention your problem.

Comment: @MohanSingh Yes I want to send updated/modified json to server

Comment: @Gaurav Sorry for delay, are you still facing the same issue?

Comment: @MohanSingh I am still facing the same issue

Comment: @Gaurav Can you create a plunker for me So i take you through step by step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not update a json file without using a server-side language like PHP or python. Basically it is security compliance. For more understanding kindly go through 
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/security
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCsp
and
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you have `getjson.php` and `savejson.php` in the server which work exactly as their names suggest.

Now use `$http` service of Angular to retrieve your json from the server.

```
$http.get("getjson.php").then(function(response){

     $scope.myJsonObject = response.data;

     //Your json becomes JS object here. Change it the way you want
     $scope.myJsonObject.text1 = "Abc"; 

});
```

Use `$http` service again to send your json back to the server.

```
$http({
           method: "post",
           url: "savejson.php",
           data: $scope.myJsonObject,
           headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' }
});
```

This is the basic. Please note that you need to do your php part to save/load your json file. Also you should handle errors of the `$http` service.

Please see how [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service and [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) work.

Comment: It will be the same json file as long as `getjson.php` and `savejson.php` deal with the same file.